# Apply Html style in grid cell content

Tags: styles, c#-2.0

I want to format a c# code in a grid cell.
I want to apply italic style to the string strProjectDelivery.
But it is not happening.

The below is the csharp string.

```
strProjectResults = strProjectGoals + "" + strProjectDelivery
```

I used the Server.HtmlEncode().

```
strProjectResults = strProjectGoals + Server.HtmlEncode("<i>"+ strProjectDelivery+"</i>");
```

And the string result is like this,

```
HighPriorityGoals&lt;i&gt;DeliveredOnTime&lt;/i&gt;
```

Even HtmlDecode is also not working.
Please let me know how to handle this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you displaying the string?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of HTML encoding is to take arbitrary text and escape its HTML tags so that it's treated as plain text.

HTML-escaping the `<i>` defeats your purpose.

Instead, you need to HTML-escape the **content** that you're building into the HTML

You need to know whether each variable is treated as HTML or as text, or you'll end up having XSS holes.

Comment: Hi SLaks, Can you please tell me how to do this html escaping in this c# string..??

Comment: @Naveen: That's what `Server.HtmlEncode()` does.  You need to understand the code you're trying to write.